# Toyota Aygo stuck in some gear

Tags: shifting, gear-stick

My daughter went to go to drive her car today and when she moved the gear shifter it jammed in some gear. The shifter will not move and the car will not select any gear. When you start the car you must press on the clutch for it to start. If you turn the key without pressing the clutch the engine will not turn and the car will not jump forward as it usually would if the car was in a gear. Once you release the clutch the car dies. Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That the gearbox is in a gear, and cannot be shifted into neutral, indicates that a) either the linkage that connects the gearshift lever to the transmission is broken or jammed, or b) something is broken or jammed within the gearbox itself.

Problem a) is probably solvable if the linkage can be exposed and worked on. This will depend upon the design of the car. Problem b) will probably require removal of the gearbox so that it can be opened and repaired on the workbench.